# Fourth page of custom post type archive page does not exist in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently developed a custom post type for my company's blog, so that we could have a separate press area. In the archive-presse.php page I make a query, thus :

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
//echo '<div style="display:hidden"> paged :'. $paged . "</div>";
$press_articles = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'presse', // Tell WordPress which post type we want
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby'   => 'post_date',
        'posts_per_page' => '10'
        )
    );
```

and at the bottom, I create the navigation links :

```
<div class="navigation">
<div class="left"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Zurück',$press_articles->max_num_pages) ?></div>
<div class="right"><?php next_posts_link('Weiter &raquo;',$press_articles->max_num_pages) ?></div>
</div>
```

(Austrian website, in case you were wondering)

On the first page, this works fine; the posts appear and so does the navigation links, which points to the second page and so on. On the third page however, when I click on 'Weiter', I end up on the 404 page, although I am sure there are still articles to be shown.

My only fix at the moment is to make sure that the posts per page is equal to a third of the total number of posts. Not much of a fix.

Comment: Close vote: exact duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59636/fourth-page-of-custom-post-type-archive-page-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one cannot apparently set `'posts_per_page'` to anything other than what is set in the admin interface, even for a custom archive page.

The same code, minus the `'posts_per_page' => 'x'` line, works fine.